# How to divide the image into several irregular parts according to this grid

Tags: image-processing

I see the method of image segmentation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6706/how-can-i-calculate-a-jigsaw-puzzle-cut-path?rq=1).
[image]

I can use the `ImagePartition` function to divide the image into several regular sub images

```
img=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn5ot.jpg"]
ImagePartition[img, 120] // Grid
```

But how to divide the image into several irregular parts according to this grid:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than trying to process the puzzle image, we can work with the procedure that produced it (from Vasiliy Kaurov's wonderful blog page [Designing Jigsaw Puzzles with Mathematica](https://blog.wolfram.com/2012/06/28/designing-jigsaw-puzzles-with-mathematica/)).

Two things we need to add: (1) We need to get polygon primitives with wiggled edges rather than lines, and (2) We need to use the input image as `Texture` for polygon primitives rather than graphics background.

```
ClearAll[bSF, jiggedlines, match, jiggedfaces, vtc, jiggle]

bSF[{p1_, p2_}] := With[{pm = Mean[{p1, p2}], dp = (p2 - p1)/5, 
   rc = RandomChoice[3 {-1, 1}/4]}, 
  BSplineFunction[{p1, pm, pm - dp + rc {1, -1} Reverse[dp], 
    pm + dp + rc {1, -1} Reverse[dp], pm, p2}, 
   SplineWeights -> {1, 15, 25, 25, 15, 1}]]

jiggedlines[mesh_] := Join[MeshPrimitives[mesh, {"Lines", "Boundary"}],
   (Join @@ (MeshPrimitives[mesh, {"Lines", #}] & /@ {"Interior", "Frontier"})) /. 
     Line[x_] /; ArcLength[Line[x]] > 0.25 :> (bSF[x] /@ Subdivide[50])] /. Line[x_] :> x;

match[coords_] := If[#[[{1, -1}]] == coords, #, Reverse@#] &@*
  SelectFirst[#[[{1, -1}]] == coords || #[[{-1, 1}]] == coords &]

jiggedfaces[mesh_] := Module[{jl = jiggedlines[mesh]}, 
   MeshPrimitives[mesh, "Polygons"] /. 
     Polygon[x_] :> Join @@ (match[#][jl] & /@ Partition[x, 2, 1, 1])];
```

***Examples:***

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVClL.jpg"];
image = ImageCrop[image, {448, 448}];

id = ImageDimensions[image];
SeedRandom[1]
vm = VoronoiMesh[Transpose[RandomReal[{0, #}, 9] & /@ id],
  Thread[{0, id}], ImageSize -> id];

Row[{Graphics[lines, ImageSize -> 400],
  Graphics[{Opacity[.7], RandomColor[], EdgeForm[Gray], Polygon@#} & /@
     jiggedfaces[vm], ImageSize -> 400]}]
```

[image]

To use the input image as `Texture` for individual polygons, we need a function to determine `VertexTextureCoordinates`:

```
vtc[mesh_] := Transpose[MapThread[Rescale[#, #2] &,
      {Transpose[#], CoordinateBounds[mesh]}]] &;
```

Texturized puzzle pieces:

```
pieces = Graphics[{Texture@image, EdgeForm[Gray], 
      Polygon[#, VertexTextureCoordinates -> vtc[vm][#]]}] & /@ jiggedfaces[vm];

Row[Panel /@ {image, 
   Pane[Grid[Partition[pieces, 3]], ImageSize -> {Automatic, 448}, 
    ImageSizeAction -> "ShrinkToFit"]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Show the pieces together or jiggle location/scale/orientation randomly:

```
ClearAll[jiggle]
jiggle[ctr_] := Function[{x, y}, Rotate[Translate[Scale[x[[1]], {.95, .95}, y], 
     RandomReal[{.05, .2}] (y - ctr)], RandomReal[{-Pi/16, Pi/16}], y]];

centroids = RegionCentroid @ jiggedfaces[vm];
center = RegionCentroid[vm];

SeedRandom[1]
Row[{Show[pieces, ImageSize -> 400], 
  Graphics[MapThread[jiggle[center], {pieces, centroids}], ImageSize -> 400]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Replace `Texture @ image` with

```
Texture @ Rasterize[Show[RemoveBackground@image, 
   Background -> Opacity[.5, ColorData["Rainbow"][RandomReal[]]]]]
```

to make pieces with different background colors:

[image]

Replace `Texture @ image` with

```
Texture @ ImageMultiply[image, Append[ RandomColor[], .3]]
```

to tint each piece with a random color:

[image]

Comment: Thanks,but where is the `polygons`?

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes, it should be `jiggedfaces[vm]`; fixed now.