# How to do a "random" image partition based on seeding points?

Tags: image-processing, image

I'm new to image analysis with Mathematica, so far it looks it has great capabilities. I'm trying to do an image partition, similar to [ImagePartition[]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePartition.html), but "random". Suppose I have the image below:

`myImage =`

[image]

Now, I can do `ImagePartition[myImage, {100,100}]`, to get sub-images of 100 by 100 pixels:

[image]

How could I, instead of this 'orderly' partition of the image, seed some random points in the image, and retrieve the {width, height} sub-images centered on each of the points. For instance, we generate some number of random points on the image:

```
myRndPts = 
  Table[{RandomInteger[ImageDimensions[myImage][[1]]], 
    RandomInteger[ImageDimensions[myImage][[2]]]}, 800];
Show[myImage, ListPlot[myRndPts,
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]]
```

[image]

Then, from the center of each point, we make a sub-image of the desired {width, height}. In doing so, what to do with points that fall on the edges of the image? Maybe trim the window size, or add some extra 'padding'?

Currently, I'm thinking on doing simply  `ImagePartition[myImage,{width,height},{dw,dh}]`, with dw=dh=1, where dw and dh are the offset of the partition. This offset would --I believe-- sample all possible subpartitions of {width, height}. Then, from this list, I could select n random elements. However, this would not be efficient with large images, since it will generate a bunch of images I won't end up using.

Thanks

Comment: See `ImageTrim`.

Comment: somewhat related:[How to divide the image into several irregular parts according to this grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/213872/125)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a given image (`im`), a list of 2D points (`pts`) and side length (`radius`), the function `rectangleCoords` finds the arguments of `Rectangle`s  centered at `pts` and forced to stay within the image rectangle.

We can use `rectangleCoords` directly with `ImageTrim`, or further process the output from `rectangleCoords` to generate row and column specs for `ImageTake`.

The function `imageTake`, given the same inputs, computes the parameters  $\{row_1, row_2\}$ and $\{col_1, col_2\}$  to get the sub-image that spans $row_1$ to $row_2$  and $col_1$ to $col_2$  using `ImageTake[im, {row_1, row_2}, {col_1,col_2}]`.

```
ClearAll[rectangleCoords, imageTake]

rectangleCoords[im_, pts_, radius_] := Transpose[
   Transpose @ MapThread[Clip[#, {1, #2}] &] @ 
    {Transpose[pts + # radius/2], ImageDimensions[im]} & /@ {-1, 1}];

imageTake[im_, pts_, radius_] := Module[{rowscols = 
    Map[Apply[{ImageDimensions[im][[2]] + 1 - Reverse @ #, #2} &] @*
       Reverse @* Transpose] @ rectangleCoords[im, pts, radius]}, 
  ImageTake[im, ##] & @@@ rowscols ]
```

***Example:***

```
myIm = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];

SeedRandom[1]
myPts = RandomSample[Tuples @ Range @ ImageDimensions @ myIm, 40];

myRadius = 60; 

Show[myIm, 
 Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point @ myPts, 
   EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[], 
   Rectangle @@@ rectangleCoords[myIm, myPts, myRadius]}],
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
ImageTrim[myIm, rectangleCoords[myIm, myPts, myRadius]] // 
  Multicolumn[#, 8] &
```

[image]

```
imageTake[myIm, myPts, myRadius] // Multicolumn[#, 8] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of fun - may not be what you want, however.

```
i = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}]
ImageDimensions@i
(* {256, 256} *)
```

Create a `VoronoiMesh` and use those polygons as a mask.

```
pts = RandomReal[{20, 236}, {10, 2}];
mp = MeshPrimitives[VoronoiMesh[pts], 2];
Show[i, Epilog -> {FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Thick], mp}]
```

[image]

```
RemoveBackground@ImageCrop@
ImageSubtract[i, Show[i, Graphics[{#}, PlotRange -> 256]]] & /@ mp
```

[image]

Comment: This is cool, maybe I'll use this for another application, haha. But yeah, I'm just trying to generate a bunch of squared sub-images, so unfortunately the Voronoi tesselation won't do the trick here. But this is cool.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, in case it is of any use to somebody, following the comment by @C.E. I took a look into [ImageTrim[]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageTrim.html). It was only a matter of finding out the specific format of the arguments of the function.

```
(*Load image*)
myIm = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f46D.jpg"];
(*Generate some random points*)
myPts = Table[{RandomInteger[ImageDimensions[myIm][[1]]], 
        RandomInteger[ImageDimensions[myIm][[2]]]}, 100];
(*Radius from each point, to make a square*)
myRadius = 10;
(*This generates the coordinates of each sub-image*)
mySubIms = Table[
       {{myPts[[i]][[1]] - (myRadius - 1), 
         myPts[[i]][[2]] - (myRadius - 1)}, 
        {myPts[[i]][[1]] + (myRadius - 1), 
         myPts[[i]][[2]] + (myRadius - 1)}},
       {i, 1, Length[myPts]}];
(*This is the list of all sub-images*)
mySubImages = ImageTrim[myIm, mySubIms]; 

(*We can visualize the overlayed sub-images*)

    Show[myIm,
     Table[Graphics[{FaceForm[None], 
        EdgeForm[Directive[Dashed, Thickness[0.005], Blue]],
        Rectangle[mySubImages[[i]][[1]], mySubImages[[i]][[2]]]}],
      {i, 1, Length[mySubImages]}]]
```

[image]

As you can see, it seems that the sub-images on the edges are simply trimmed, which for my application is fine. Maybe adding some padding would be preferred for some other applications.

Feel free to improve or make this method more efficient. I wrote things step by step, for clarity, but maybe there are some performance improvements if needed for large images.