# Generating a (random) 2-dimensional cellular network

Tags: graphs-and-networks, random

I want to generate a network of random cells like the following picture:

[image]

The general idea is to generate some random points (x,y) as coordinate of a vertex and then randomly choose some of these points to connect them to achieve (almost) a  random cellular network since there are two constraints:

1. The length of edges is constant.
2. Degree of each vertex is 3.

Thanks,

*Update*

I have been thinking about this problem for a while. Here's the conclusion:

By starting from a perfect honeycomb, we perform a series of random "neighbor switching" process:

[image]

By performing successive neighbor switching, we are able to build cells with different size.

Comment: What have you tried? Post at least some code showing attempts: In general, this site is not intended as a "will work for free and rep. points" kind of place...

Comment: If you really want all edge lengths to be the same, I think you end up seeing only the three regular tilings of a plane; not very random.

Comment: @kirma: Only if you also constrain angles to force the polygons to be regular. Otherwise I think there is quite a bit of freedom.

Comment: @rasher: I have tried to generate some vortices (x,y) by "RandomReal" function. Then I tried to choose randomly a vertex and connect that to three other vortex since degree of each vertex should be 3. I should choose those three points from neighbors which I can do that by defining a upper limit on the distance. The main problem is to keep the length of edge the same and the degree 3.

Comment: @kirma: That's right. It's not completely random but since the length of edge represents a chemical bond, it should be the same for all cells.

Comment: Run [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2606/12) then `ListDensityPlot[
 ArrayFlatten[{{pts, RandomReal[1, {Length[pts], 1}]}}], 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, Mesh -> All]`.  Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 7):

Fixing the edge length makes the problem harder. Otherwise, maybe this here gives an idea

```
<< ComputationalGeometry`
data = .9 Flatten[
    Table[{x, y} + .07 RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2}], {x, -1, 
      1, .2}, {y, -1, 1, .2}], 1];
delval = DelaunayTriangulation[data];
convexHull = ConvexHull[data];
gr = DiagramPlot[data, ##, LabelPoints -> False] & @@ 
 BoundedDiagram[{{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, data, delval, 
  convexHull]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and further

```
gr /. {Point[___] :> Sequence[], 
  Line[pts_] :> ({EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], 
     ColorData["Rainbow", RandomReal[]], Polygon[pts]})}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Might generate the random points like this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2594/12

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the idea. Maybe 'DelaunayTriangulation' is not the choice here and I have to have a specific code for this part.