# Distribution of 10 points within a unit square

Tags: mathematical-optimization, random, geometry, code-request, packing

Related to some packing problems, following problem arose:

**Distribute 10 points within a square of sides 1, so that minimal distance between them is maximized.**

With the help of random simulation, or any other method, please provide example of such distribution, with graphical representation of square and points, and value of minimal distance between points for such distribution.

The answer with distribution with largest minimal distance wins the "answer badge"! :)

*(This problem so far to my knowledge couldn't be solved by pure mathematics, so I am coming here for valuable and desperately needed help regarding simulations etc.)*

Comment: You could use `NMaximize`.

Comment: Possibly related: [(2594)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2594)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since this does seem to be a kind of packing problem I searched for prior explorations, and found a list of packings for equal-circles within a square at:

- http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/csq/d1.html

The best known packing for N = 10 is shown as:

[image]

The coordinates for the points are:

> ```
>    1  -0.055497063038156969690135505676  -0.351795677434771201331992637257
>    2   0.240911582092300627645879219810  -0.351795677434771201331992637257
>    3  -0.351795677434771201331992637257  -0.343720034134076580133895794673
>    4   0.055387032304313603995977911771  -0.076908787408790806346486820340
>    5   0.351795677434771201331992637257  -0.076908787408790806346486820339
>    6  -0.351795677434771201331992637257  -0.047311389003618982797881069187
>    7  -0.132623434010086730621834242216   0.152242144215576109267055784036
>    8   0.351795677434771201331992637257   0.219499857721666790989527905147
>    9  -0.351795677434771201331992637257   0.351795677434771201331992637257
>   10   0.086548809414597740088324152827   0.351795677434771201331992637257
> ```

Plotted:

```
pts = {{-0.0554971`, -0.351796`}, {0.240912`, -0.351796`}, {-0.351796`, -0.34372`},
 {0.055387`, -0.0769088`}, {0.351796`, -0.0769088`}, {-0.351796`, -0.0473114`},
 {-0.132623`, 0.152242`}, {0.351796`, 0.2195`}, {-0.351796`, 0.351796`},
 {0.0865488`, 0.351796`}};

m = Min @ pts;

Graphics[{
  {LightBlue, Rectangle[{m, m}, -{m, m}]},
  {Red, AbsolutePointSize[15], Point @ pts}
}]
```

[image]

The minimal distance between points (full precision, and scaled to a unit square) is: **0.42127954398...**

I suspect a better solution will not be forthcoming.

---

#### Old comments

Blatantly copying Simon's code, but messing with optimization parameters I get this:

```
pts = Array[{x[#], y[#]} &, 10];
mindist2 = Min[#.# & /@ Subtract @@@ Subsets[pts, {2}]];
vars = Flatten[pts];
constraints = Thread[0 <= vars <= 1];
{md2, rules} = 
  NMaximize[{mindist2, constraints}, vars, 
   Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution",
              "CrossProbability" -> 0.6,
              "ScalingFactor" -> 0.68,
              "RandomSeed" -> 42}];

minimaldistance = Sqrt[md2]

Graphics[{Yellow, Rectangle[], Red, PointSize[Large], Point[pts /. rules]}]
```

> ```
> 0.417788
> ```

[image]

This is a better result, but I have zero confidence that it is optimal.  I wonder how else one might approach this.

Answer (score 18):

A simple numerical maximization using `NMaximize` as suggested by b.gatessucks:

```
pts = Array[{x[#], y[#]} &, 10];
mindist2 = Min[#.# & /@ Subtract @@@ Subsets[pts, {2}]];
vars = Flatten[pts];
constraints = Thread[0 <= vars <= 1];
{md2, rules} = NMaximize[{mindist2, constraints}, vars];

minimaldistance = Sqrt[md2]
(* 0.381759 *)

Graphics[{Yellow, Rectangle[], Red, PointSize[Large], Point[pts /. rules]}]
```

[image]

**Update**

Rahul Narain's comment informs us that to maximize $\min(f_1,...,f_n)$ it is typically more efficient to introduce a new variable $t$ and maximize that with the constraints $t\le f_1,...,t\le f_n$. Modifying the code to work that way, and blatantly copying Mr. Wizard's method optimizations gives an improved result:

```
pts = Array[{x[#], y[#]} &, 10];
dist2 = #.# & /@ Subtract @@@ Subsets[pts, {2}];
vars = Flatten[pts];
constraints = Thread[0 <= vars <= 1] ~Join~ Thread[mindist < dist2];
{md2, rules} = NMaximize[{mindist, constraints}, Append[vars, mindist], 
  Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "CrossProbability" -> 0.6, 
    "ScalingFactor" -> 0.68, "RandomSeed" -> 42}];

minimaldistance = Sqrt[md2]
(* 0.421268 *)
```

[image]

Comment: Typically in optimization, if you want to maximize $\min(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ it is more efficient to maximize a new variable $t$ subject to the constraints $t\le f_1, \ldots, t\le f_n$.

Comment: So, it looks NMaximize returned some kind of local maximum 0.38 (the other answer has 0.42)!

Comment: Just to put my money where my mouth is, simply doing `NMaximize[{t, Join[Thread[t <= List @@ mindist2], constraints]}, Append[vars, t]]` without any messing with optimization parameters gives a minimal distance of $0.419542$.

Comment: @RahulNarain, thanks! I've just added your solution to my post.

Comment: I guess we did it simultaneously. :) It's gratifying that your new solution seems to be the same as the best known packing posted by Mr.Wizard under a reflection across the NE/SW diagonal.

Comment: FYI: my "method optimizations" were random values that seemed to work OK, not something special.  Changing those values acted like a chaos system which is why I went searching for something else.

Comment: Also FYI: using the numbers referenced in my answer I believe the optimal (known) spacing is: 0.4212795 -- I wonder if that can be coaxed out of *Mathematica*?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, perhaps with sufficient runs with different random seeds! Otherwise it probably needs someone who really understands numerical optimization. Personally I just treat `NMaximize` as a black box full of magic.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Simon: Try setting `MaxIterations -> 200` and no other parameters. I get a minimum distance of 0.4212794349471961.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks, that's what I was looking for.